# ASP.Net site using Windows Authentication pops up "Authentication Required Window" a lot in Firefox

Tags: asp.net, firefox, windows-authentication

I have an ASP.Net application where I am using Windows authentication to deny access to some components via roles.  When using IE, the site pops up the "Authentication Required" box once, allows the user to enter their username/password for Active Directory, and all is fine.

HOWEVER, when using Firefox, it's "Authentication Required" box pops up, but when you click 'ok', it comes up again!  It stays up a few dozen times!  If you click cancel to all of them, it fails properly, denying access to the site.  If you click cancel to all but 1 (Which you authenticate properly), it acts like you were properly authenticated.

My goal here is to have Firefox act like IE, and only ask the user once.

Comment: What do you see in your IIS logs?  Turn on ALL logging.  You should see a status 401, followed by a 200 which includes the cs-username you'd expect.  Compare the log results you are getting for IE / Firefox..

Comment: 2nd thought - is it possible a corporate proxy is getting the in way?  if this is the case you won't see anything in your logs from firefox.

Comment: I am hitting the localhost, so i don't think its the proxy.  It seems like all of the WebResource.xsd requests are prompting an extra Authentication Requested.  IE seems to be 'caching' the security for the whole site, so it doesn't fail for every single file on the system.  Any idea why this would happen?

Comment: when you look in your logs does firefox sucessfuly GET the axd after you type the password - or is it continuing to get denied?

Comment: If i type in my username and password every time correctly, it gets a code 200 properly.  However, it seems to have a ton of those axd requests that it is doing, as well as a few other files.  I've switched my webconfig to only cover the individual aspx pages (through the location tab), but it doesnt stop it!

It almost seems like firefox isnt properly caching the login info as IE does.

Comment: i've updated my answer with some info on keep-alive..  i can repro your prob if i turn off keep-alive in IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This forum post recommends updating your web.config to allow anon on WebResource.axd: http://forums.asp.net/p/1295804/2515478.aspx#2515478

Not ideal - I don't really understand WHY axd requests are behaving like this.

NOTE: NTLM requires keep-alive, if you install fiddler or firebug you should be able to see the "Connection: keep-alive" messages in the request header: http://davenport.sourceforge.net/ntlm.html#ntlmHttpAuthentication

Comment: From what you gave me, i found this: http://www.jimandkatrin.com/codeblog/2007/09/anonymous-access-with-webresourceaxd.html which is basically the same problem I was having.

Additionally, I had 'digest auth' instead of 'integrated auth'.  Now it even uses the current account if the user has permissions.

Thanks!

Comment: Broken link - shame information wasn't shared on StackOverflow :(

Comment: Hopefully you found a solution to your problem in the last 11 years but here's an archive link for the link above: https://web.archive.org/web/20110719061835/http://www.jimandkatrin.com/CodeBlog/post/Anonymous-Access-with-WebResourceaxd.aspx

Answer (score 1):

you could get Firefox to behave exacylt like IE by adding the site to 
about:config >>
network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris
then firefox will use Windows Auth for the site

Comment: This actually does not work, it still asks for credentials a bunch of times.  My other problem is this is I dont have total control over the user's environment.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe it would be best to redesign your login/authentication system such that authentication is asked only when the user first views/logs-in to the website (i.e. a login.aspx page) so that after that the users's credentials are cached throughout your website.

Comment: This is how Windows Auth is supposed to work.  It asks via the normal browser pop-up for the authentication information (returning a 401 if the browser doesn't send proper authentication information).

IE seems to be 'caching' this for the entire download-transaction, however Firefox seems not to.  I'm beginning to think this is an improper implementation on firefox's part.